# paypal : order create , invalid link after 3 hours

Tags: paypal

We have created an api , in order to create a direct payment for a customer with paypal.
So we created a "create order" as capture.

We can get the approve link to the customer for the payment.
unfortunately , if the customer doesn t pay in the next 3 hours , we have this message :
"You were inactive for a while, so we logged you out to protect your account. Go back to the merchant's website and start over."

How to extend the duration before logged out? Indeed our customer would pay in the next day ou 2 days ....

We found this in the documentation :
'To complete payer approval, use the approve link to redirect the payer. The API caller has 3 hours (default setting, this which can be changed by your account manager to 24/48/72 hours to accommodate your use case) from the time the order is created, to redirect your payer'

Do you know where is this configuration on the paypal backoffice ?
we didn t find it :(
Do you think it s the good information for our case?

Thanks a lot
Thomas

Answer (score 1):

When you [create a PayPal v2 order](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders-create-request-body), it will be valid for 72 hours.

Once the buyer loads the checkout approval for that order, from that point on it will be valid for only 3 hours, then expire.

If you want a PayPal link to be valid for longer, consider using Invoicing instead: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/invoicing/basic-integration/ .  Invoices can be generated and sent as an email, or as a link.

---

Otherwise, if invoicing doesn't fit your use case and you need a link to be valid for more than 72 hours... you should create your own order checkout link on your own site, and have it create the PayPal order on-demand when the payer is actually ready to check out (and clicks a PayPal button on your site). This can be a pretty good experience since you can use smart buttons for the PayPal checkout to open the approval flow, and also have a black Debit or Credit Card button that expands a form within your site (as a secure iframe). See the demo pattern at: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server